# Node.js Redis client doesn't have Redis commands

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a trouble with [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) package. There's in it's docs:

> This library is a 1 to 1 mapping of the Redis commands.

But I can not access Redis commands through this lib's client.

I'm creating a client like this:

```
const client = createClient({
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: +process.env.REDIS_PORT!,
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD
  }
});
```

`createClient` is imported this way: `import { createClient } from 'redis';`

And when I try to call any Redis command on this client, e.g.:

```
client.rpush('key', 'value');
```

I get an error:
`this.client.rpush is not a function`

And `console.log(Object.keys(client));` output is:

```
[
  '_events',
  '_eventsCount',
  '_maxListeners',
  'select',
  'subscribe',
  'pSubscribe',
  'unsubscribe',
  'pUnsubscribe',
  'quit'
]
```

Am I doing something wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: These "raw" clients usually accept...well...raw redis commands so you could try `client.RPUSH`. Having said that, and looking into your client it would seem you need to do something first (connect)? Have you looked into the clients [README](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Redis Commands](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#redis-commands) section in the README file,

> There is built-in support for all of the out-of-the-box Redis commands. They are exposed using the raw Redis command names (HSET, HGETALL, etc.) and a friendlier camel-cased version (hSet, hGetAll, etc.):

So, use the rpush command as `client.RPUSH('key', 'value');` or `client.rPush('key', 'value');`